# ASPNET Core 2.0: Is there a way to access IOptions without constructor pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am aware of constructor pattern to get to a configured IOptions e.g.

```
public SomeClass(IOptions<SomeOptions> someOptions)
{
}
```

However, I have run into a scenario where I have an existing method where I want to access SomeOptions. I do not want to change the signature for the constructor of that class. Is there any other way to access SomeOptions?

Comment: You're introducing a new dependency, so the class *should* change. Why is it that you don't want to change the constructor? If you're trying to maintain backwards compatibility for consumers of a library, you can either introduce an additional constructor for this (leaving the original as-is) and simply add some sort of fallback for the original constructor, or create a new version of your class, marking the original as deprecated.

Comment: It's abstract base class, which has many sub classes, all of them call the existing base class constructor. If I change the signature, I will have to bring IOptions dependency in all those classes.

Answer (score 2):

This is the "service locator" anti-pattern, but you can retrieve services from the DI container within controllers or any of the other base classes that give you an instance of `HttpContext`:

```cs
var opts = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IOptions));
```

Comment: While this *is* very much an anti-pattern that you really shouldn't be using, it's worth noting that you'd *still* need to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into your class to access `HttpContext`, unless the "class" here just happened to be a controller, which it most likely isn't.

Comment: @ChrisPratt it is also available from Razor Pages. I wrote "other base classes" because offhand I couldn't remember if there were others beyond those two.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't saying *just* controller, but I'd imagine the class in question here isn't any class of the sort that would have HttpContext built in.

Comment: Yeah, the class I have doesn't have HttpContext, but thanks anyways for sharing this way of getting to IOptions (will be useful if it's really required).

Comment: I hate to suggest this because it's an even worse variation on Doing It Wrong, but you could establish a static reference to `IServiceProvider` during startup. All of this is classified as, "just because you _can_ doesn't mean you _should_"...

Answer (score 0):

Built-in DI container in ASP.NET Core is very simple and supports dependency injection only via constructor. In your case, you have 2 options (as you don't want to change the ctor signature)

- setup and use any other DI container that supports dependency injection via method/property etc
- or pass `IOptions<SomeOptions>` as the argument to your `existing method`. But you will need to get options from DI container in some other place before calling the method though.